# Sending HTTPS requests in Google App Engine using requests python library

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, ssl, python-requests, google-translate

The title pretty much sums it up, I am making a request to the google translate api like this:

```
    payload = {"key":translate_api_key, "q":str(sentence)}
    try:
        api_response = requests.get("https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate   /v2/detect", params=payload)

    except Exception, e:
        print e
```

this works fine normally (by which i mean just running it as a script on my desktop) but on the google app engine server I am getting this response:

```
{u'error': {u'message': u'SSL is required to perform this operation.', u'code': 403, u'errors': [{u'message': u'SSL is required to perform this operation.', u'domain': u'global', u'reason': u'sslRequired'}]}}
```

How can I fix this?

EDIT:
Seems request's https doesn't play nicely with GAE. Using urlfetch and urllib seems to fix this.

```
payload = dict(key=translate_api_key, q=sentence) 
payload = urllib.urlencode(payload) 
url = "https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2/detect?"
api_response = urlfetch.fetch(url+payload)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no experience of using the **requests** library, but it may be that it is not fully implemented on App Engine.

The preferred method on App Engine is to use [urlfetch](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/#Python_Fetching_URLs_in_Python)

```
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch

url = "https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2/detect"

payload = {"key":translate_api_key, "q":str(sentence)}

result = urlfetch.fetch(url=url, payload=payload)
if result.status_code == 200:
  api_response = result.content
```

Comment: Thanks! That didn't quite work as urlfetch doesn't automatically encode the sentence but this: 

`payload = dict(key=translate_api_key, q=sentence)  payload = urllib.urlencode(payload)  
url = "https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2/detect?"    
api_response = urlfetch.fetch(url+payload)` (sorry - can't get the formatting working) seems to work okay - funnily using the payload parameter isn't working here so im resorting to concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try in the app.yaml

```
handlers:
- url: /youraccount/.*
  script: accounts.py
  login: required
  secure: always
```

The `secure:always` makes **your** site ssl. I'm not sure this is that actual problem though.

Answer (score 0):

GCP does not support the use of Requests library out of the box. So we will have to make some tweeks to make it work.
In order to deploy an application on the Google App Engine, we need to make a main.py(where main python flask app resides) and app.yaml(configuration file needed to run it in GCP).
Here is a sample code for the app.yaml file for python 2.7 environment

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: flask
  version: 0.12
```

Now we need to configure the requests library to use URLfetch internally.
To use requests, we'll need to install both requests and requests-toolbelt using the vendoring instructions. (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#installing_a_library). 
Basically we need to install our custom libraries.

1. Create a directory to store your third-party libraries, such as lib/
   mkdir lib
2. Upload the requests and requests-toolbelt libraries from your system or download them directly into the lib folder created in earlier step.
3. Use pip (version 6 or later) with the -t  flag to copy the libraries into the folder you created in the previous step. For example:
   pip install -t lib/    (pip install -t lib/ requests)
4. Create a file named appengine_config.py in the same folder as your app.yaml file.
5. Edit the appengine_config.py file and provide your library directory to the vendor.add() method.
   Sample appengine_config.py file

   from google.appengine.ext import vendor

   ## Add any libraries install in the "lib" folder.

   vendor.add('lib/requests')
   vendor.add('lib/requests_toolbelt')
6. Once installed, use the requests_toolbelt.adapters.appengine module to configure requests to use URLFetch.
   Copy the below code to the start of your main.py file

   import requests
   from requests_toolbelt.adapters import appengine
   appengine.monkeypatch(validate_certificate=True)

(https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/issue-requests)

Now we can easily use the requests library to make get/post requests.
Test your app:

```
dev_appserver.py --port=<port number> app.yaml
```